# How to connect to SharePoint list using Objective-C / Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to connect to a list on a SharePoint 2010 site using Objective-C within xCode.  Is anyone able to point me in the right direction here?  I am very familiar with developing in SharePoint - it is the Objective-C which is giving e problems.  Thank you....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two services available: one SOAP and one REST.

The SOAP service is called Lists.aspx and is available at [site address]/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx

The REST (actually oData) service is called ListData.svc and is available at [site address]/_vti_bin/ListData.svc

In both cases you need to pass credentials with the service calls which I do not know how to do in Objective-C / XCode.

Comment: Thanks Rob. The connection I am making is using the SOAP service, so thanks for reassuring me that I am on the right lines, although I haven't actually got it working yet. I think that GetListCollection will serve the right purpose once I am there.

If anyone has experience of this from the Objective-C angle - particularly accessing the list items themselves -  I would appreciate the advice...thanks

Comment: @MarkLeighton as a bit of advice, work with REST since SOAP will be deprecated by Microsoft in the future releases. Also, if you happen to work with 2013 or Office 365, the new REST service (client.svc) offers about as much power as regular CSOM.

Answer (score 3):

The best way would be to create a web service to expose the functionality you want from SharePoint, in fact I believe Sharepoint might already have some web services for this.

Then to consume it, if it is SOAP use sudzc.

Comment: The BEST way is to rely on webservices exposed by Sharepoint, such as Lists.asmx (or other .asmx services) or REST APIs (ListData.svc for 2010 and Client.svc for 2013).

Answer (score 0):

I found this somewhere else but it should a great start for you

```
NSString *soapFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                        "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                        "<soap:Body>\n"
                        "<GetListCollection xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/\" />\n"
                        "</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>\n"];


    NSLog(@"Request is : %@",soapFormat);

    NSURL *locationOfWebService = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.0.114/_vti_bin/lists.asmx"];

    NSLog(@"Web url = %@",locationOfWebService);

    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:locationOfWebService];

    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[soapFormat length]];


    [theRequest addValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue:@"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetListCollection"
                            forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];


[theRequest addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    //the below encoding is used to send data over the net
    [theRequest setHTTPBody:[soapFormat dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    NSURLConnection *connect = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    if (connect) {
        webData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"No Connection established");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sharepoint 2010 and 2013 now have a RestFul API, which can be accessed at 'http://site_url/_api'.

From here you can append /_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('list_name') and you will be able to get the lists contents. You can do more with this api. To read up more on supported operations, visit [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164022.aspx)